# Выделение запятыми слова "кажется"

Tags: пунктуация

**На эту тему написано так много, что() кажется() добавить больше нечего.**

Чем является "кажется" в данном предложении и нужно ли выделять его запятыми?
Можно ли поставить двоеточие?

Answer (score 2):

"Кажется" здесь – вводное слово, выделяется запятыми. Где вы хотите поставить двоеточие? после "кажется"? Наверное, не стоит – получится слишком вычурно. Но тогда перед "кажется" запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 1):

**На эту тему написано так много, что кажется ― добавить больше нечего.**

Предложения с постановкой тире (но не двоеточия) в природе существуют, но у них обычно вторая часть (после тире) **является более распространенной** (не инфинитив, а  двусоставное предложение) , поэтому  после паузы она  **читается более естественно.**

Нас швыряет на сиденьях так, что **кажется ― вот-вот душа расстанется с телом**. [В. В. Овчинников. Вознесение в Шамбалу (2006)]

Но художественное проникновение писателя в суть сталинского режима настолько глубоко, **что кажется ― он сидел все эти три дня в первом ряду в зале суда**. [М. Д. Голубовский. Биотерапия рака, «дело КР» и сталинизм // «Звезда», 2003]

Comment: A чем является "кажется" в данном предложении?

Comment: Это сказуемое в предложении 2, а между 2 и 3 бессоюзная связь. Сравнить: На эту тему написано так много, что кажется, что  добавить больше нечего. Бессоюзная связь используется, чтобы  избежать повтора союза ЧТО.

Comment: @ Sibylla, а в каком значении употреблено это сказуемое?

Comment: КАЗАТЬСЯ. 2. безл. кому. Представляться воображению, мысли. Мне кажется, что мы уже где-то встречались.

Comment: @Sibylla,но здесь можно без ущерба смысла убрать "кажется", и тогда его можно считать вводным.

Comment: 1) Замена: На эту тему написано так много, что вроде бы добавить больше нечего. Смысл не изменился, вариант с тире только выделяет вторую часть предложения. 2) Нас швыряет на сиденьях так, что вроде бы вот-вот душа расстанется с телом. Здесь такая замена не подойдет.  Вводное слово или модальное сказуемое - надо смотреть по смыслу в каждом случае.

Comment: @Sibylla,  мы говорим о нашем случае. А здесь возможны два варианта.

Comment: Да, два варианта: стандартный с обособлением запятыми и нестандартный - обособление тире. Выбор на усмотрение автора. Семантика практически не меняется,  но второй вариант более эмоциональный, больше экспрессии.